# Create a virtual host which redirects from httpd to tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, virtualhost

I want to point an url say `example.com` to `http://localhost:8081`. I have added entry in `/etc/hosts` file from `example.com` to `localhost`. But problem is that port 8081 is configured to be used by tomcat server and port 80 is used by apache2 httpd server. In `apache2.conf` file I have created a virtual host to redirect `example.com` to `http://localhost:8081` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      example.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is giving following error:

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

So what I think is that the problem is due to different servers. If 8081 had been on httpd, this would have worked. What is the workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: __If 8081 had been on httpd, this would have worked__ - not true. Doesn't matter what port services are running on, you just need to make sure one can access the other. The message you're getting means that's exactly what's not happening. Are these both running on the same server?

Comment: It is always good to use AJP protocol in scenarios such as above. It an optimized version of the HTTP protocol to allow a standalone web server such as Apache to talk to Tomcat. However - looks like http://localhost:8081 is not available. Two checks could be performed. 1) Access http://localhost:8081 and make sure its available. 2) Verify that port 8081 from  to tomcat server is open.